# PHP Fatal Error on 'php artisan migrate' on remote AWS EB instance: laravel.log: Permission denied

Tags: amazon-web-services, laravel-5, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, database-migration, laravel-artisan

When I SSH into my AWS EB instance to run `php artisan migrate`, I get the following error message:

[Link to bigger size of picture below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OzwAG.jpg)

[image: php fatal error on running php artisan migrate on eb instance]

I am completely confused. First, I don't get this error on the local server. Second, what does a simple log file have to do with migrations anyway? They are ignored by git by default, so no log files are uploaded.

Sigh... Any ideas on how I can be allowed to run my `php artisan migrate`?

Comment: It's trying to write something to the log folder, for which the permissions are not set up correctly.

Comment: Aha. Now I'm that much smarter. You wouldn't happen to know how to allow the application to write to the log? Thanks for your time by the by :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's always the storage folder. Blank pages or permission denied, it's the darn storage folder.

I don't know how EB works, if it's a regular distro or what, but you should change ownership of the storage folder to the web server (www-data most likely) so it can build the views then set `775` permission so you can write/read logs.

So something like:

```
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data storage/
sudo chmod -R 775 storage/
```

Comment: You were right. Damn storage folder was the culprit. It worked when I did the following command: `sudo chmod -R ugo+rw storage`

Answer (score 1):

I've gone through the same error

[image]

As stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59148275/5675325),

> AWS AMI uses webapp as the web user, not apache or ec2-user as the
> file shows. In that case, the webapp user has no access rights over
> those files.

So, going through the steps mentioned in there fixed the problem

```
sudo chown $USER:webapp ./storage -R

find ./storage -type d -exec chmod 775 {} \;

find ./storage -type f -exec chmod 664 {} \;
```

Depending on what you're aiming to do afterwards [you might need to go through this too](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65485115/5675325).