# How to add Laravel env file in AWS AutoScaling

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, environment-variables, autoscaling

I am working on a laravel project which is hosted on AMAZON AWS. We are also using **AWS AutoScaling** service, since new instances can be added/removed on the fly, I am also using **AWS CodeDeploy** so whenever a new instance will be created it will pull the code from github as we do not include environment variable file on git so new instance will not have the environment variable file so the application will not be able to run. I also do not want to include the environment variable file on git as it is not recommended to include that file on git. If I ignore the best practices here and add the env file on git then still there is a problem as I have different branches with different env files so when I merge the code it will replace the env file as well. So what are the best practices or solutions for this case ?

FYI: we are not using **ElasticBeanstalk** as I am familiar that on elastic beanstalk there is an option on **EB** dashboard to add environment variables and the path where env file will create upon new instance creation but we are not using **ElasticBeanstalk**, we are using **AutoScaling** service and according to my findings AWS do not provide such functionality for **AutoScaling** service.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set environment variables for Laravel 5 on AWS EC2 with MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28721365/how-to-set-environment-variables-for-laravel-5-on-aws-ec2-with-mysql)

Comment: Actually we can do something like that if we use elastic beanstalk but we are not using elastic beanstalk, we are using auto scaling and we cannot add environment variables in auto scaling on aws according to my findings.

Comment: Does anyone came across the best practices to do this job?

Answer (score 0):

There are several options to configure the env vars for an application.

1. Place the env files on S3 and on boot in the user data/launch config for that environments auto scaling pull down the config file for that env. Also to lock it down in the role for an environment only allow access to that bucket.
2. Store the env vars in Dynamodb for the env, and on boot look those up in user data and set at env vars. (unless the contain secrets/connection strings, et al., no way to store encrypted secrets in DDB. )
3. Use Consul https://www.consul.io/

> KV Store: Applications can make use of Consul's hierarchical key/value store for any number of purposes, including dynamic configuration, feature flagging, coordination, leader election, and more. The simple HTTP API makes it easy to use.