# Environment Variables in newest AWS EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, environment-variables

I am trying to get ENVIRONMENT Variables into the EC2 instance (trying to run a django app on Amazon Linux AMI 2018.03.0 (HVM), SSD Volume Type ami-0ff8a91507f77f867 ).   How do you get them in the newest version of amazon's linux, or get the logging so it can be traced.

user-data text (modified from [here](https://github.com/12moons/ec2-tags-env/blob/master/import-tags.sh)):

```
#!/bin/bash
#trying to get a file made
touch /tmp/testfile.txt
cat 'This and that' > /tmp/testfile.txt
#trying to log
echo 'Woot!' > /home/ec2-user/user-script-output.txt

#Trying to get the output logged to see what is going wrong
exec > >(tee /var/log/user-data.log|logger -t user-data ) 2>&1

#trying to log
echo "XXXXXXXXXX  STARTING USER DATA SCRIPT    XXXXXXXXXXXXXX"

#trying to store the ENVIRONMENT VARIABLES
PARAMETER_PATH='/'
REGION='us-east-1'
# Functions
AWS="/usr/local/bin/aws"

get_parameter_store_tags() {
    echo $($AWS ssm get-parameters-by-path --with-decryption --path ${PARAMETER_PATH}  --region ${REGION})
}

params_to_env () {
    params=$1

    # If .Ta1gs does not exist we assume ssm Parameteres object.
    SELECTOR="Name"

    for key in $(echo $params | /usr/bin/jq -r ".[][].${SELECTOR}"); do
                value=$(echo $params | /usr/bin/jq -r ".[][] | select(.${SELECTOR}==\"$key\") | .Value")
                key=$(echo "${key##*/}" | /usr/bin/tr ':' '_' | /usr/bin/tr '-' '_' | /usr/bin/tr '[:lower:]' '[:upper:]')
                export $key="$value"
                echo "$key=$value"
    done
}


# Get TAGS
if [ -z "$PARAMETER_PATH" ]
      then
              echo "Please provide a parameter store path. -p option"
              exit 1
fi
TAGS=$(get_parameter_store_tags ${PARAMETER_PATH} ${REGION})
echo "Tags fetched via ssm from ${PARAMETER_PATH} ${REGION}"

echo "Adding new variables..."
params_to_env "$TAGS"
```

Notes -

- What i think i know but am unsure

  - the user-data script is only loaded when it is created, not when I stop and then start mentioned [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/user-data.html#user-data-shell-scripts) (although it also says [i think outdated] that the output is logged to `/var/log/cloud-init-output.log` )
  - I may not be starting the instance correctly
  - I don't know where to store the bash script so that it can be executed
- What I have verified

  - the user-data text is on the instance by ssh-ing in and `curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/user-data` shows the current text (`#!/bin/bash …`)
- What Ive tried

  - editing `rc.local` directly to `export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID='JEFEJEFEJEFEJEFE' …` and the like
  - putting them in the AWS Parameter Store (and can see them via the correct call, I just can't trace getting them into the EC2 instance without logs or confirming if the user-data is getting run)
  - putting ENV variables in Tags and importing them as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28643573/how-to-set-an-environment-variable-in-amazon-ec2):
  - tried outputting the logs to other files as suggested [here](https://alestic.com/2010/12/ec2-user-data-output/) (Not seeing any log files in the ssh instance or on the system log)
  - viewing the `System Log` on the aws webpage to see any errors/logs via selecting the instance -> 'Actions' -> 'Instance Settings' -> 'Get System Log'  (not seeing any commands run or log statements [only 1 unrelated word of `user`])

Comment: What is the current state - what is (or is not) actually happening? What is the target state?

Comment: I don't have any logs showing. It appears the user-data script isn't being executed.    the instance starts.  `printenv` prints other environment variables, but none of the ones I tried to add.

Comment: Do you stop/start the instance or run it for the first time? userdata won't be run during next reboots

Comment: See https://superuser.com/questions/1095113/how-to-configure-aws-ec2-user-data-values-and-bash-script